# How to find a pattern of strings in a 2D array?

Tags: go

Trying write a function in go to count a pattern in a 2D array. For example in the array below, A T A (row 1)A A (row2) appears twice so the output should an int 2. I've attempted to write code

below and wanted to understand where I'm going wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

```
 func CountingPattern(c [][]string, p [][]string) int {
        positions := StartingIndices(c, p)
        return len(positions)
    }
    
    func StartingIndices(x [][]string, k [][]string) []int{
        var positionSlice int
        lenText := len(x)
        for i := 0; i<= lenText-len(k); i++ {
            for j := 0; i<= lenText-len(k); i++{
                if x[i:i+len(k)][j:j+len(k)] == k {
                    positionSlice = append(positionSlice, i)
            }
        }
        return positionSlice
    }
```

Comment: With a simple reading of your question, I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. But right off the bat, I notice that your nested loop defines `j` and never manipulates it, but instead manipulates the `i` variable from the outer loop. That strikes me as a mistake.

Comment: I'm trying to find how many times a pattern of strings is repeated throughout the array. I want to loop through the array and if a pattern is found I want it to add to the count. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I think that something along these lines should do you.

**Disclaimer: Untested**

First let's define an `Offset` type that we can use to identify the locus of a [potential] match within the "data" array.

```
type Offset struct {
  row int
  col int
}
```

Then, we can identify all the matches simply by iterating over the "data" array by row and then by column, and testing for a match at that point — any matches found are appended to the returned slice:

```
func FindMatches(data [][]byte, pattern [][]byte) (matches []Offset) {
  
  for r := range data {
    for c := range data[r] {
      offset := Offset{r, c}
      
      if matched := isMatch(pattern, data, offset); matched {
        matches = append(matches, offset)
      }
      
    }
  }
  
  return matches
}
```

Testing for a match is pretty straightforward. We accept the "pattern" array, the "data" array, and an `Offset` indicating the location within the "data" array where matching to to begin. This code:

- Makes an initial assumption that we have a match
- iterates over the pattern array, row, by row. For each row in the pattern,

  - Attempts to slice the appropriate bits from the data array
  - The match is a failure if we couldn't get the needed bits from the
    data aray. Reasons that might fail include

    - insufficient rows
    - insufficient cols
  - We then iterate over every column in the pattern row and

```
func isMatch(pattern, data [][]byte, offset Offset) (matched bool) {
  
  matched = true
  
  for r := range pattern {
    var patternRow, dataRow []byte
    
    patternRow = pattern[r]
    dataRow, matched = sliceRow(data, r+offset.row, offset.col, len(patternRow))
    
    matched = matched && bytes.Equal(patternRow, dataRow)
    if !matched {
      return matched;
    }
    
  }
  
  return matched
}
```

And finally, slicing out the appropriate bits of a row in the "data" array is  equally simple. This accepts as parameters

- the data array
- a row offset
- a column offset
- the number of columns required

It fails if the specified row lies outside the data array or the columns requested would extend past the end of the current row:

```
func sliceRow(data [][]byte, r, c, n int) (row []byte, ok bool) {
  lo := c
  hi := c+n
  
  ok = r < len(data) && hi <= len(data[r])
  if !ok {
    return row, ok
  }
  
  row = data[r][c:c+n]
  
  return row, ok
}
```